# ANSI C - scope of variables

Tags: c

C++ programmer here, recently been roped in to do some C programming.
Looking for a refresher on the rules of variable scope in ANSI C compliant code.

Is the following code ANSI C compliant?

```
void foo_func(void)
{
    int i = 0;

    printf("i = %d\n", i);

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j) {
       printf("j = %d\n", j);
    }
}
```

Does variable `j` need to be declared at the start of the function?
My understanding is that `for()` implicitly starts a new scope. That is; even before the opening brace.

Does the same apply for `while()` and `if()`?
And what about `do.. while()` ?

Do the rules of scope differ between C89 and C99 or later?

Comment: ANSI C is the *current* C. I assume you mean the colloquial for C89. Your code is valid C99 and C11. It's invalid C89.

Comment: What is C98, please?

Comment: C89 means the C Standard published(?) in that year (it might be the proposal year).  Basically its the version of the C Standard.

Comment: Typo: C89 (fixed)

Comment: @StoryTeller No, "ANSI C" is C89. ANSI have had _nothing_ to do with the C language since the year 1989. ANSI does not even publish national software standards any longer, that is handled by another American institute called INCITS. The C language is specified by an international ISO/IEC standard, ISO 9899. In USA _only_, this standard is called INCITS/ISO/IEC 9899-2012.

Comment: @Lundin - ANSI ratified C11, so technically, ANSI C *is* C11.

Comment: @StoryTeller They did not. INCITS did. As did any other national standard institute in the world, through their working groups. Should I go around and call it "SS C" because I live in Sweden?

Comment: @Lundin - Are we arguing the meaning of "ratified" now? They officially adopted it. That's what they consider "C". So yes, call it "SS C" if you want. The phrasing does not imply ownership, only association.

Comment: @Lundin @StoryTeller - Sorry to have caused a disagreement between you two about the correct use of `ANSI`. Perhaps a citation from either one of you can settle the dispute, but please note that doing so was not the point of my question. I am happy with the notion that `ANSI` is a vague term in this context.

Comment: It can easily be settled by acknowledging that ANSI and INCITS are _American national standard institutes_ and Stack Overflow is an _international_ site. We don't care about anything but international standards here, period.

Comment: @Lundin - Rubbish. You may have that opinion, and I don't discount it's validity. But "you" is not "we". And that is not something SO will ever take a stance on formally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does variable j need to be declared at the start of the function?

Yes, if you are using C89. Or, at least you'd need to introduce a scope with `{ ..}` and declare it.

> Does the same apply for while() and if()? And what about do.. while() ?

The syntax doesn't permit declaring variables in (i.e., `while (int i = 0)` isn't valid) them. But you can declare *insde* them which is allowed in all C standards.

> Do the rules of scope differ between C98 and C99 or later?

There's no C98 but yes the rules changed in C99 and later and allows you declare variables in the `for` loop (as you have in your code).

> Is the following code ANSI C compliant?

That depends on what "ANSI C" refers to. It's valid in C99 and later.

Comment: Thanks, I made a typo in my original question. It was meant to read "C89", but I think you guessed as much.

Comment: Also, asking if the same applies for the other loop / conditional cases was a bit a stupid (side-)question on my part.

Comment: "ANSI C" is slightly ambigous. I am never sure whether it's referring the *current* standard (C11) or the C89 (usually people refer it as "ANSI C").
So it's better to avoid it IMHO. Yes, I understood your question and hopeuflly I have answered it!

Answer (score 2):

`>> My understanding is that for() implicitly starts a new scope. That is; even before the opening brace.`

Correct.
From [C11 standards#6.8.5p5 Iteration statements](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.5p5)

> An iteration statement is a block whose scope is a strict subset of the scope of its enclosing block. The loop body is also a block whose scope is a strict subset of the scope of the iteration statement.

This holds true for [C99](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.pdf) as well.

`>> Does the same apply for while() and if()? And what about do.. while() ?`

In `if()`, `while()` and `do..while()` loops you can not declare the variable like `if (int j = 0)` or `while(int j = 0)`.

Comment: Re: Yeah. I feel stupid suggesting the same might apply for `while()` and `do... while()`. Or even `if()` for that matter.

Comment: @iwarv You shouldn't. Being able to do e.g. `if((Handle h = OpenSomething(..)) != HANDLE_INVALID) { ...` would be awesome, in my opinion.

Comment: @unwind Pretty much all companies I have ever worked for strictly prohibit such compounded statements in their coding standards, perhaps for the right reasons. But a good point. I feel a little less stupid. Thanks.